# How can i jail a user in linux?

Tags: linux

That's is the question.. how can i jail a user in a certain folder so that he can create files like images but can no go up using the command `cd ..` or see other folders outside?

Thanks.

Comment: You might give your user a restricted shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about chroot http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot

You can even create a minimal environment for the user

Alternatively just use file permissions so that the user is only able to see what the user should be able to.

Comment: thanks for the point of chroot. Looking at it. And if i want to set permissions can you give an idea of it?

Comment: chmod - http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod - chgrp, groups etc.